# How can I make my boxes scale accordingly when the browser is resized

Tags: html, css

My boxes at present work and display on the page as I would like, (they will eventually contain a pic and a description) but as of now they aren't responsive in that they scale down in size accordinly, to maintain the width to height ratio I have specified.

**CSS:**

```
#pageArea {
    display: block;
    margin: 5px auto;   
    max-width: 1200px;
    position: relative; 
}

.projectListingLarge {
    width: 42%;
    height: 479px;
    margin: 0 3% 5% 0;
    background-color: blue;
    float: left;    
}

.projectListingSmall {
    width: 25%;
    height: 200px;
    float: left;    
    margin: 0 3% 5% 0;
  background-color: green;
}

.mS {
  margin-top: 500px !important;
}

.right {
  float: right !important;
}
```

I have tried setting a `max-height`, but it doesn't behave at all then, and just shrinks to the content of the `div`. I have also tried a percentage as a height, but the box just disappears.

I know a media query will help the float, depending on screen size, but until the media query kicks in at `1050px`, how can I make it so my boxes scale down accordingly?

https://jsfiddle.net/s5g1bzva/1/

Comment: its not clear for me what should happen when browser resize?

Comment: @S.Serp the width of the boxes is relative of the screen, when the browser is resized, but the height is not. It stays fixed at the px measuremnt. I thought a % for the height would work, but it hasn't...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To scale divs proportionally you would need to set the `height` to `0` and assign a `padding-bottom` in percentage (relative to the width).

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x2qns1xg/1/)

```css
#pageArea {
  display: block;
  margin: 5px auto;
  max-width: 1200px;
  position: relative;
}

.projectListingLarge {
  width: 42%;
  padding-bottom: 60%;
  height: 0;
  margin: 0 3% 5% 0;
  background-color: blue;
  float: left;
}

.projectListingSmall {
  width: 25%;
  padding-bottom: 30%;
  height: 0;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 3% 5% 0;
  background-color: green;
}

.mS {
  margin-top: 500px !important;
}

.right {
  float: right !important;
}

.clearBoth {
  clear: both;
  height: -1px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="pageArea">
  <article class="projectListingLarge"></article>

  <article class="projectListingSmall mS">s</article>

  <article class="projectListingSmall right">s</article>

  <div class="clearBoth">

  </div>

  <!-- second batch -->

  <article class="projectListingLarge"></article>

  <article class="projectListingSmall mS">s</article>

  <article class="projectListingSmall right">s</article>

</div>
```

(The above is just an example, you would need to set the correct padding-bottom percentage for your case.)

Answer (score 0):

Setting height as percentage usually won't help, and that's not just limited by scaling your browser but because most browsers don't relate it to screen size. The best thing to do is to change their content's size, or their heights in px for different screen resolutions.
Try using "@media screen and (max width: **YourSize**px) { [Your new css rules...] }"